# Why /etc/sudoers failed when doesn`t use absolute path?

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

I want to give my account `nova` sudo priviledge so I  add this configure to /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults:nova !requiretty

nova ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /openstack/bin/nova-rootwrap 
/etc/nova/rootwrap.conf *
nova ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/privsep-helper *
```

Then I switch to nova:

```
su - nova
```

Here is the question:
When I execute `sudo /openstack/bin/nova-rootwrap`, it works, but when I execute `sudo nova-rootwrap`, the system ask me the password. Seems that the `NOPASSWD` not work.

I have already added `/openstack/bin` to my env path. System is CentOS7.4.

Why does this happen? How can I execute it withoute password?

Comment: If you enter the password does it allow `nova-rootwrap` to run?  If so, then @Spooler's comment below explains the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that someone can change path, and make nova-rootwrap filled with some malicious code.

There is really good discussion regarding this topic -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Comment: Sorry, but seems that change path is not the root cause. I have added "Default !secure_path" to /etc/sudoers and the problem is also exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your command to switch users isn't updating the environment, preserving the environment of your previous user. Using a login shell instead of using only "-" will accomplish this more completely.

That is, if you want a completely new environment you should be doing this:

`su --login nova`

This also works:

`sudo -i nova`

Answer (score 0):

It's security reason, because it's really bad idea to give sudo without full path or give sudo to script which is own by non privileged user, because you grant them root privilege in that moment.